# How to make Elemental Gemm run quickly?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, parallel-computing, mpi, blas

How to make Elemental Gemm run quickly?

I have the following code:

```
#include "elemental.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace elem;

extern "C" {
    void openblas_set_num_threads(int num_threads);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    Initialize( argc, argv );
    const mpi::Comm comm = mpi::COMM_WORLD;
    const int commRank = mpi::CommRank( comm );
    const int commSize = mpi::CommSize( comm );

    try {
        const int n = Input("--n","size of matrices",1000);
        const int nb = Input("--nb","algorithmic blocksize",128);
        int r = Input("--r","process grid height",0);
        ProcessInput();

        SetBlocksize( nb );
        // If no process grid height was specified, try for a square
        if( r == 0 )
            r = Grid::FindFactor( commSize );
        Grid g( comm, r );

        Matrix<double> A, B, C;
        Uniform( A, n, n );
        Uniform( B, n, n );
        Uniform( C, n, n );
        mpi::Barrier( comm );
        Timer timer;
        if( commRank == 0 ) {
            timer.Start();
            Gemm( NORMAL, NORMAL, 1., A, B, 0., C );
            std::cout << "Multithreaded time: " << timer.Stop() << " secs"
                      << std::endl;  

            openblas_set_num_threads(1);
            timer.Start();
            Gemm( NORMAL, NORMAL, 1., A, B, 0., C );
            std::cout << "Sequential time: " << timer.Stop() << " secs"
                      << std::endl;  
        }
        openblas_set_num_threads(1);

        if( commRank == 0 )
            timer.Start();
        DistMatrix<double,CIRC,CIRC> ARoot(n,n,g), BRoot(n,n,g); 
        if( commRank == 0 ) {
            ARoot.Matrix() = A;
            BRoot.Matrix() = B;
            std::cout << "Population time: " << timer.Stop() << " secs"
                      << std::endl;
        }

        if( commRank == 0 )
            timer.Start();
        DistMatrix<double> ADist( ARoot ), BDist( BRoot ), CDist(g);
        Zeros( CDist, n, n );
        mpi::Barrier( comm );
        if( commRank == 0 ) 
            std::cout << "Scatter from root: " << timer.Stop() << " secs"
                      << std::endl;

        if( commRank == 0 )
            timer.Start();
        Gemm( NORMAL, NORMAL, 1., ADist, BDist, 0., CDist ); 
        mpi::Barrier( comm );   
        if( commRank == 0 ) 
            std::cout << "Distributed: " << timer.Stop() << " secs"
                      << std::endl;

        DistMatrix<double,CIRC,CIRC> CRoot( CDist );
        mpi::Barrier( comm );
        if( commRank == 0 ) 
            std::cout << "Gather to root: " << timer.Stop() << " secs"
                      << std::endl;
    } catch( std::exception& e ) { ReportException(e); }
    Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running on 4 nodes, each node with 12 cores.  The blas is OpenBLAS, compiled from source, so it supports 12 threads, and affinity is turned off.  I get the following results for gemm, with n=4000:

- multithreaded blas, via Elemental Matrix: **1.6s**
- singlethreaded blas. via Elemental Matrix: 11.9s
- DistMatrix, 1 mpi processes, singlethreaded blas: 13.3 seconds
- DistMatrix, 4 mpi processes, singlethreaded blas: 6.6 seconds
- DistMatrix, 48 mpi processes, singlethreaded blas: 30.2  seconds

I also tried using multithreaded blas with DistMatrix, by commenting out the lines `openblas_set_num_threads(1)` in the above code, and got the following results:

- DistMatrix, 4 mpi processes, multithreaded blas: 4.5 seconds

Why am I getting times for the DistMatrix on 4 nodes which are not competitive with the multithreaded blas time on a single compute node?

Edit: I also tried setting A to MC,STAR; and B to STAR,MR, following page 27 of "Rethinking distributed dense linear algebra", by Jack Poulson 2012, but the results were no better for me:

- DistMatrix, mpi 4 processes, multithreaded blas: 6.2 seconds
- DistMatrix, mpi 48 processes, singlethreaded blas: 35.3 seconds

Edit 2: added code to prevent any code being optimized out, ie the functions `readMatrix`, and the `cout << sum << endl` at the end, but no change in timings:

- blas single-threaded: 12.2 seconds
- blas multi-threaded: **1.6** seconds
- DistMatrix 4 nodes, 4 processes, multithreaded blas: 4.5 seconds
- DistMatrix 4 nodes, 48 processes, singlethreaded blas: **29.8** seconds

Edit 3: note that scalapack sdgemm also seems to run more slowly than multithreaded blas for me, but faster than Elemental, for me:

scalapack sdgemm, 4 nodes, 4 processes, multithreaded blas: 2.11 seconds
scalapack sdgemm, 4 nodes, 48 processes, singlethreaded blas: 29.1 seconds

Note that for both scalapack and elemental, it seems that it is faster to use one mpi process one node, and turn on OpenBLAS multithreading, than to use one mpi process per core, and turn off OpenBLAS multithreading.  Which makes sense, since one can then take advantage of shared memory, reducing the amount of communications required?

code for scalapack tests:

```
#pragma once

extern "C" {
    struct DESC{
        int DTYPE_;
        int CTXT_;
        int M_;
        int N_;
        int MB_;
        int NB_;
        int RSRC_;
        int CSRC_;
        int LLD_;
    } ;

    void blacs_pinfo_( int *iam, int *nprocs );
    void blacs_get_( int *icontxt, int *what, int *val );
    void blacs_gridinit_( int *icontxt, char *order, int *nprow, int *npcol );
    void blacs_gridinfo_( int *context, int *nprow, int *npcol, int *myrow, int *mycol );
    void blacs_gridexit_( int *context );
    void blacs_exit_( int *code );

    int numroc_( int *n, int *nb, int *iproc, int *isrcproc, int *nprocs );
    void descinit_( struct DESC *desc, int *m, int *n, int *mb, int *nb, int *irsrc, int *icsrc, int *ictxt, int *lld, int *info );
    void pdlaprnt_( int *m, int *n, double *a, int *ia, int *ja, struct DESC *desca, int *irprnt,
        int *icprnt, const char *cmatnm, int *nout, double *work, int cmtnmlen );
    void pdgemm_( char *transa, char *transb, int *m, int *n, int *k, double *alpha,
         double *a, int *ia, int *ja, struct DESC *desca, double *b, int *ib, int *jb,
        struct DESC *descb, double *beta, double *c, int *ic, int *jc, struct DESC *descc );
}

void blacs_pinfo( int *p, int *P ) {
    blacs_pinfo_( p, P );
}

int blacs_get( int icontxt, int what ) {
    int val;
    blacs_get_( &icontxt, &what, &val );
    return val;
}

int blacs_gridinit( int icontxt, bool isColumnMajor, int nprow, int npcol ) {
    int newcontext = icontxt;
    char order = isColumnMajor ? 'C' : 'R';
    blacs_gridinit_( &newcontext, &order, &nprow, &npcol );
    return newcontext;
}

void blacs_gridinfo( int context, int nprow, int npcol, int *myrow, int *mycol ) {
    blacs_gridinfo_( &context, &nprow, &npcol, myrow, mycol );
}

void blacs_gridexit( int context ) {
    blacs_gridexit_( &context );
}

void blacs_exit( int code ) {
    blacs_exit_( &code );
}

int numroc( int n, int nb, int iproc, int isrcproc, int nprocs ) {
    return numroc_( &n, &nb, &iproc, &isrcproc, &nprocs );
}

void descinit( struct DESC *desc, int m, int n, int mb, int nb, int irsrc, int icsrc, int ictxt, int lld ) {
    int info;
    descinit_( desc, &m, &n, &mb, &nb, &irsrc, &icsrc, &ictxt, &lld, &info );
    if( info != 0 ) {
        throw runtime_error( "non zero info: " + toString( info ) );
    }
//    return info;
}

void pdlaprnt( int m, int n, double *A, int ia, int ja, struct DESC *desc, int irprnt,
    int icprnt, const char *cmatnm, int nout, double *work ) {
    int cmatnmlen = strlen(cmatnm);
    pdlaprnt_( &m, &n, A, &ia, &ja, desc, &irprnt, &icprnt, cmatnm, &nout, work, cmatnmlen );
}

void pdgemm( bool isTransA, bool isTransB, int m, int n, int k, double alpha,
     double *a, int ia, int ja, struct DESC *desca, double *b, int ib, int jb,
    struct DESC *descb, double beta, double *c, int ic, int jc, struct DESC *descc ) {
    char transa = isTransA ? 'T' : 'N';
    char transb = isTransB ? 'T' : 'N';
    pdgemm_( &transa, &transb, &m, &n, &k, &alpha, a, &ia, &ja, desca, b, &ib, &jb,
        descb, &beta, c, &ic, &jc, descc );
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#include "cpputils.h"

#include "args.h"
#include "scalapack.h"

extern "C" {
    void openblas_set_num_threads(int num_threads);
}

int getRootFactor( int n ) {
    for( int t = sqrt(n); t > 0; t-- ) {
        if( n % t == 0 ) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// conventions:
// M_ by N_ matrix block-partitioned into MB_ by NB_ blocks, then
// distributed according to 2d block-cyclic scheme

// based on http://acts.nersc.gov/scalapack/hands-on/exercise3/pspblasdriver.f.html

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int p, P;
    blacs_pinfo( &p, &P );
    mpi_print( toString(p) + " / " + toString(P) );

    int n;
    int numthreads;
    Args( argc, argv ).arg("N", &n ).arg("numthreads", &numthreads ).go();
    openblas_set_num_threads( numthreads );

    int nprows = getRootFactor(P);
    int npcols = P / nprows;
    if( p == 0 ) cout << "grid: " << nprows << " x " << npcols << endl;

    int system = blacs_get( -1, 0 );
    int grid = blacs_gridinit( system, true, nprows, npcols );
    if( p == 0 ) cout << "system context " << system << " grid context: " << grid << endl;

    int myrow, mycol;
    blacs_gridinfo( grid, nprows, npcols, &myrow, &mycol );
    mpi_print("grid, me: " + toString(myrow) + ", " + toString(mycol) );

    if( myrow >= nprows || mycol >= npcols ) {
        mpi_print("not needed, exiting");
        blacs_gridexit( grid );
        blacs_exit(0);
        exit(0);
    }

    // A     B       C
    // m x k k x n = m x n
    // nb: blocksize

    // nprows: process grid, number rows
    // npcols: process grid, number cols
    // myrow: process grid, our row
    // mycol: process grid, our col
    int m = n;
    int k = n;
//    int nb = min(n,128); // nb is column block size for A, and row blocks size for B
    int nb=min(n/P,128);

    int mp = numroc( m, nb, myrow, 0, nprows ); // mp number rows A owned by this process
    int kp = numroc( k, nb, myrow, 0, nprows ); // kp number rows B owned by this process
    int kq = numroc( k, nb, mycol, 0, npcols ); // kq number cols A owned by this process
    int nq = numroc( n, nb, mycol, 0, npcols ); // nq number cols B owned by this process
    mpi_print( "mp " + toString(mp) + " kp " + toString(kp) + " kq " + toString(kq) + " nq " + toString(nq) );

    struct DESC desca, descb, descc;
    descinit( (&desca), m, k, nb, nb, 0, 0, grid, max(1, mp) );
    descinit( (&descb), k, n, nb, nb, 0, 0, grid, max(1, kp) );
    descinit( (&descc), m, n, nb, nb, 0, 0, grid, max(1, mp) );
    mpi_print( "desca.LLD_ " + toString(desca.LLD_) + " kq " + toString(kq) );
    double *ipa = new double[desca.LLD_ * kq];
    double *ipb = new double[descb.LLD_ * nq];
    double *ipc = new double[descc.LLD_ * nq];

    for( int i = 0; i < desca.LLD_ * kq; i++ ) {
        ipa[i] = p;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < descb.LLD_ * nq; i++ ) {
        ipb[i] = p;
    }

    if( p == 0 ) cout << "created matrices" << endl;
    double *work = new double[nb];
    if( n <=5 ) {
        pdlaprnt( n, n, ipa, 1, 1, &desca, 0, 0, "A", 6, work );
        pdlaprnt( n, n, ipb, 1, 1, &descb, 0, 0, "B", 6, work );
    }

    NanoTimer timer;
    pdgemm( false, false, m, n, k, 1,
                  ipa, 1, 1, &desca, ipb, 1, 1, &descb,
                  1, ipc, 1, 1, &descc );
    MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    if( p == 0 ) timer.toc("pdgemm");

    blacs_gridexit( grid );
    blacs_exit(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from Jack Poulson's elemental/examples/blas-like/Gemm.cpp program, run with `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 mpirun.mpich2 -hosts host3,host1,host2,host4 48 ./ElementalExampleGemm --m 2000 --n 2000 --k 2000 --nb 128`, ie 48 processes, 1 thread per process:

```
g: 6 x 8
Sequential: 1.74586 secs and 9.16452 GFLops
Populate root node: 0.0340741 secs
Spread from root: 0.443471 secs
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.0068028 secs, 50.2758 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.224466 secs, 1.14048 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00301719 secs and 7.08474 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00582409 secs, 58.7244 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.221785 secs, 1.15427 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00290704 secs and 7.35319 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00559711 secs, 61.1058 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.258585 secs, 0.990002 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00293088 secs and 7.29337 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00562692 secs, 60.7821 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.266162 secs, 0.961821 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00652504 secs and 3.276 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00574803 secs, 59.5014 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.253986 secs, 1.00793 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00300407 secs and 7.11567 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00567889 secs, 60.2258 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.263011 secs, 0.973343 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00289297 secs and 7.38894 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00561213 secs, 60.9422 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.0310259 secs, 8.25117 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00288296 secs and 7.41461 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00552988 secs, 61.8487 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.229407 secs, 1.11592 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00290298 secs and 7.36346 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00556993 secs, 61.4039 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.259156 secs, 0.987822 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00277686 secs and 7.6979 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00564504 secs, 60.587 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.260839 secs, 0.981448 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00277185 secs and 7.7118 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00549412 secs, 62.2513 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.224814 secs, 1.13872 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00276208 secs and 7.7391 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00556684 secs, 61.4381 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.216236 secs, 1.18389 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00276899 secs and 7.71977 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00551414 secs, 62.0252 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.22506 secs, 1.13747 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00276208 secs and 7.7391 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.005409 secs, 63.2309 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.255941 secs, 1.00023 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00276995 secs and 7.71712 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00536704 secs, 63.7252 MB/s for 334 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.225583 secs, 1.13484 MB/s for 128 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00295305 secs and 7.23861 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00358391 secs, 59.6444 MB/s for 334 x 80 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.251425 secs, 0.636373 MB/s for 80 x 250 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00167489 secs and 7.97664 GFlops for 334 x 250 x 80 product
Distributed Gemm: 3.80641 secs
Gathered to root: 0.399101 secs
```

Edit: and results for 4 mpi processes (on 4 12-core nodes), run with `mpirun.mpich2 -hosts host3,host1,host2,host4 -np 4 ./ElementalExampleGemm --m 2000 --n 2000 --k 2000 --nb 128`, ie with OpenBLAS multithreading activated:

```
g: 2 x 2
Sequential: 0.219173 secs and 73.0017 GFLops
Populate root node: 0.035708 secs
Spread from root: 0.482837 secs
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.0147331 secs, 69.5035 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.010592 secs, 96.6769 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00869703 secs and 29.4353 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00796413 secs, 128.576 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00883698 secs, 115.877 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00752282 secs and 34.0298 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00717402 secs, 142.737 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.0083642 secs, 122.427 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00796413 secs and 32.1441 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00718212 secs, 142.576 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.0080409 secs, 127.349 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00650787 secs and 39.337 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00641584 secs, 159.605 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00688195 secs, 148.795 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00576997 secs and 44.3677 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00597095 secs, 171.497 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00652695 secs, 156.888 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00652885 secs and 39.2106 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00575399 secs, 177.963 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00634193 secs, 161.465 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00574183 secs and 44.5851 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00563598 secs, 181.69 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00627708 secs, 163.133 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00576282 secs and 44.4227 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.005867 secs, 174.535 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00619698 secs, 165.242 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.01108 secs and 23.1046 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00589108 secs, 173.822 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00623584 secs, 164.212 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00559402 secs and 45.7632 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00580001 secs, 176.551 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00648689 secs, 157.857 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00570703 secs and 44.857 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00566101 secs, 180.886 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00638199 secs, 160.452 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00575209 secs and 44.5056 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00572801 secs, 178.771 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00630784 secs, 162.338 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.005795 secs and 44.176 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00581098 secs, 176.218 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00644612 secs, 158.855 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00571203 secs and 44.8177 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00570321 secs, 179.548 MB/s for 1000 x 128 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00653315 secs, 156.739 MB/s for 128 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00570703 secs and 44.857 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 128 product
[MC,* ] AllGather: 0.00371313 secs, 172.361 MB/s for 1000 x 80 local matrix
[* ,MR] AllGather: 0.00396085 secs, 161.582 MB/s for 80 x 1000 local matrix
Local gemm: 0.00396299 secs and 40.3735 GFlops for 1000 x 1000 x 80 product
Distributed Gemm: 0.327859 secs
Gathered to root: 0.237197 secs
```

Comment: It would help if you said how you've launched your jobs (e.g., `mpirun -np 48 ./Gemm --n 2000 --nb 128 --r 12`), what MPI implementation (and version) you used, what your architecture is, and what your interconnect is. Note that I extended your example to allow for easily configuring the blocksize and process grid dimensions.

Comment: In the original example, to run it: `mpirun.mpich2 -hosts host1,host2,host3,host4 -np 48 ./Gemm 4000`.  Using mpich2 2.3.  Four x86 blades connected with gigabit ethernet in a single chassis.

Comment: As I suspected, you seem to be running one MPI process per node. If you are using the default build mode for Elemental, PureRelease, then you should launch one MPI process per *core* and use single-threaded BLAS. If you are using the HybridRelease mode, then you should ensure that the number of MPI processes times the number of threads per process is equal to the number of cores.

Comment: -np 48 means 48 mpi processes, and I only have 4 compute nodes, so that is 12 processes per compute node... (note: I'm not an mpi newbie; I know mpi quite well; what I am new to is distributed blas)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your usage of "48 mpi nodes". As a sanity check you may want to look at what the chosen grid dimensions were (via ``g.Height()`` and ``g.Width()``). Something pathological has to be going on, as square Gemm is perhaps the simplest routine in Elemental.

Comment: Added `if( p == 0 ) cout << "grid: " << g.Height() << " x " << g.Width() << endl;`.  Result: `grid: 6 x 8`

Comment: (hmmm, you're right about my terminology, changed `nodes` to `processes` in my description above

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in making more precise statements about where the time is being spent in Gemm, you might want to take a look at [the following example driver which I just created](https://github.com/poulson/Elemental/blob/master/examples/blas-like/Gemm.cpp).

For instance,
`mpirun -np 48 ./Gemm --m 2000 --n 2000 --k 2000 --nb 128`
will run an instrumented version of your example code which reports the local MB/s and GFlop/s achieved in the `MPI_Allgather` and `dgemm` calls which take place at each stage of the algorithm. If the achieved local GFlops within the distributed Gemm are sufficiently lower than what that of the sequential Gemm, then you may want to look into your BLAS stack. If the AllGathers are performing terribly, then you may want to look into your MPI configuration. Roughly speaking, ScaLAPACK's `pdgemm` works similarly to Elemental's, but it uses the equivalent of `MPI_Bcast` where Elemental uses `MPI_Allgather`. You might want to measure the achieved MB/s in `MPI_Bcast` versus `MPI_Allgather` on your machine for the same result size.

Comment: Ok, I will have a try. Note that this is somewhat related to an earlier question asking my MPI_Bcast is much slower than MPI_Reduce on my machines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007943/why-is-mpi-bcast-so-much-slower-than-mpi-reduce

Comment: Posted results from this into the question

Comment: (also added results using only 4 mpi processes. since we're not calling openblas_set_num_threads(1), this uses the multithreaded OpenBLAS blas, and runs much faster than using 48 mpi processes).

Comment: A thought: is the problem that the 'normal operating environment' for scalapack and elemental is a faster network than gigabit ethernet? Maybe fibrechannel or similar?  What results do you get in fact on your cluster(s)?

Comment: Hugh, I think you are missing the fact that you built the MPI-only version of the library, so your 48 MPI process job should have been launched with the environment variable ``OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`` (or whatever the equivalent is). You should be launching at most one thread per core on typical machines (Blue Gene/Q is an exception). As for Gigabit Ethernet being unusual for distributed-memory computing: yes, both its bandwidth and latency are lacking.

Comment: You think that gigabit ethernet is the reason why my results are poor?  If so, do you think there is a way around this, or should I try to find some way of getting access to faster network connections?

Comment: I think you missed the first half of my last comment...

Comment: True, but I've run experiments with openblasnumthreads set to 1 or 12, and you can see that I get much faster results with 12 threads per process, 4 mpi processes; compared to 1 thread per process, 48 processes; so the first half of the reply doesn't explain why using distributed blas is slower than directly using multithreaded OpenBLAS gemm, on my machines.

Comment: If you post the data for the properly ran (i.e., one thread per MPI process) 48-process/4-node run, then it will be easier to draw that conclusion. After looking at this case, you may also want to experiment with different algorithmic blocksizes (``nb``) and different grid heights (``r``).

Comment: Ok, I've updated the result for the 48-process run, prefixing the commandline with `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`.

Comment: It's the network.

Answer (score 2):

My best take is that your problem is simply too small. If you use MPI, it's true that you get more processors working on your problem, but they have to exchange data rather slowly using the external network. With such a small matrix, you may well get the execution time down to very small numbers by using enough processors via MPI, but the network communication time will then dominate and be the time reported as the overall run time.

To find out more about what it really is, you need to do parameter studies: run your tests with a variety of matrices of size 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 1e4, ... and plot graphs of the run time. You will see that different implementations will behave differently as the problems become larger.

Comment: Ok, good idea.  So I've spent my morning doing that, and drawn a graph.  I did it for scalapack rather than elemental because... just because I guess I figure that if I can't get good results with scalapack, I'm not going to get good results with elemental either.  Since the graph is not for elemental, I've created a new scalapack question to contain the results: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7766/performance-or-tuning-possible-for-scalapack-gemm